# include .php file in .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootbox

recently working on `boot.Dialog`  in `Bootbox.js` to show a panel to edit information, now I want to **bind data to a drop down list** in the panel by grab data from `LoadData.php`, how can I include a `.php` file in `.js` file?

```
$DropDownArray = new Array();

bootbox.Dialog( function() {
   message: "something to show";
}
```

Comment: What is in the PHP file? a database call?

Comment: You can't "include" a  PHP file from javascript. There's a number of ways to request content from a URL via javascript, for example https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ or doAjax

Comment: Not sure what are you trying, but you can try with load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: the php file is with few declared variable